# default rendering of elements within an absolutely positioned box?

Tags: css

I have set `<body>` to be absolutely positioned so that it takes up the entire viewport without having to specify a height:

```
body {
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;

    min-height: 500px;
}
```

I want to know whether the elements that I layout within the body will have any "layout" (IE speak) attached to them or will they flow normally as if the body wasn't positioned absolutely?

Comment: Depends upon there position. If you set them as absolute then their positioning will not b related to the parent body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the body will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The styling of one element doesn't influence the styling of other elements. The IE internal `hasLayout`-attribute is only set for `block`- and `inline-block`-elements. If you style your `body` to be positioned absolute, the child elements will still have their default styling.

Comment: @good_computer I don't know what your real question is, but `hasLayout` could be triggered by many CS properties in IE, e.g. `zoom: 1;`. You really should rephrase your question and make clear what your problem is, instead of speculating about which elements has which property.